# Getting Current Location instead of Cache ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I have searched a lot and didn't get any satisfactory answer, I have a scenario where I am showing a list of sellers based on user's current location. I am getting a location for the first time and when I run my App afterward whenever I try to get the location I am getting a cache location data. I did try after some time even after every 24 hours but still getting the cache location where my current location is changed as well. Following is the code I am using for reference. please advise.

Property defined in Header file

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

- (void)startSingleLocationRequest
{       
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];


}

#pragma mark --didUpdateLocations
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations{



    self.latitudeValue =  locations.lastObject.coordinate.latitude;
    self.longitudeValue =  locations.lastObject.coordinate.longitude;
// location set for simulation to UK
    if(self.latitudeValue != 51.509979 && self.longitudeValue != -0.133700){
         [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.outletSearchNearBy animated:YES];
           [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        abc *slv =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"abc"];
        slv.receivedLatitudeValue = self.latitudeValue;
        slv.receivedLongitudeValue = self.longitudeValue;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:slv animated:YES];
    }
    else{}

}
```

Comment: I'm little confused on your question. Getting current location instead cache or Getting cache instead current location?

Comment: Current location as i am always getting cache location whenever i try to fetch for the current once. it gives me location data which was once given. i am not getting the newer location data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like,

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

for(int i=0;i<locations.count;i++){
    CLLocation * newLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:i];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theLocation = newLocation.coordinate;
    CLLocationAccuracy theAccuracy = newLocation.horizontalAccuracy;

    NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];

    if (locationAge > 5.0)
    {
        continue;
    }



       // do your all stuff here and then

       break;

    }


}
```

Your code will not executes if your location age is more than 5 seconds. You can decide location age lie 10 seconds or 20 seconds!

**Update :**

Just replace your property declaration

```
 @property (nonatomic,retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

with

```
 @property (nonatomic,strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

**or**

just declare it as instance variable like,

```
 CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

and remove self from avery instance of it!

Second thing,

You should do first,

```
  [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

and then start update of location,

```
  [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: i have written the following code where you have mentioned "// do your all stuff here" but still it is showing the cache location, i have also set the value from 5.0 to 15.0.               self.latitudeValue =  theLocation.latitude;
            self.longitudeValue =  theLocation.longitude;
        
         DLog(@"Received latitude value %f",self.latitudeValue);
         DLog(@"Received longitude value %f",self.longitudeValue);

Comment: keep that value lesser. put breakpoint in it and check when your code executes ?  inshort if your locationage is larger than 3 or 5 your code should not be execute and you should not stop updation location. Second thing are you testing in device or simulator ?

Comment: i am testing on real device, still getting the cache location. i also set a breakpoint and it ran for 3 times with the same data.

Comment: which device are you using ?

Comment: iphone 6s plus with latest iOS release

Comment: I have checked your code again and I found that your property has `retained` specifier! May I know why ? Refer my update in answer!

Comment: lion i did change the code as instructed , changed retain with strong, also i did change the order of execution like [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]; and then startupdating location once. still getting the same latitude longitude value

Comment: how are you doing testing ? I mean how do you come to know that it is cached location ?

Comment: i am showing the latitude and longitude value on map and over there i am shown the location which is really far away.

Comment: Lion i am able to get the location data after deleting the app and clean the project. currently the location is not accurate at all (1km difference from my location to the coordinated values). can you please advice

Comment: Then set desired accuracy to best! Why 10 meters ?

Comment: i am still facing the same issue, i checked the location last night and after 12 hours when i moved 10km and checked the location again, still getting the old location data? Can anyone please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this

```
self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
```

Because it

- Specifies that location updates may automatically be paused when possible.
- By default, this is YES for applications linked against iOS 6.0 or later.

On the other hand, `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` uses top speed GPS. So better to use this instead of `kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters`.

Comment: Himanth i tried what you mentioned but still the result is same as the cache data.

Answer (score 0):

Lion thanks for the support, actually i was checking location inside the plaza and due to that i was not getting the right location, i tested by coming outside and it is showing perfectly. anyways thanks lion you have been really helpful.